# How to search in multiple directories in Atom editor

Tags: search, ide, atom-editor, code-editor

I have several folders in my project as the sample structure below.

```
parent-directory
 | sub-directory-1
 | sub-directory-2
 | sub-directory-3
 | ....
 | sub-directory-n
```

While searching for a string in all the files in the `parent-directory` using Atom editor, it takes a lot of time to fetch the results.

But if the search is limited to a particular folder like '`parent-directory/sub-directory-n`' the search time gets reduced considerably.

Now the challenge is that I'm unable to search inside specific folders at once. I tried all the different combinations below, but nothing seems to be working fine.

```
parent-directory/sub-directory-1;parent-directory/sub-directory-2
parent-directory/sub-directory-1+parent-directory/sub-directory-2
parent-directory/sub-directory-1,parent-directory/sub-directory-2
```

Please let me know if there is such an option available in the Atom editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your are using the parent directory name also. You need to use the child and path in there. See below screenshot

[image: Multi directory search]

As you can see I am able to search multiple directory. But I don't use the main folder `insomnia` in my path

Comment: Yes you are right. But seems like my question itself is wrong as this combination `parent-directory/sub-directory-1,parent-directory/sub-directory-2` seems to be working fine now.  Thanks anyways :)